# Luxon vs DayJS converting to UTC when in DST

Tags: date, luxon, dayjs

I'm wondering which library is doing this correctly. I think it is Luxon because it outputs what I want, but now I am not sure which is correct. Basically March 17 will be in DST. I establish a time in UTC, I change the timezone to PST, then I convert back. Luxon produces 8am UTC which is 9am with DST, but Dayjs produces 7am UTC which is 8am with DST.

```
  const dj1 = dayjs("2022-03-17T16:00:00Z");
  const djtz1 = dj1.tz("America/Los_Angeles");
  const lux1 = DateTime.fromJSDate(d).setZone("America/Los_Angeles");
  console.log(djtz1.utc().format());
  console.log(lux1.setZone("utc").toISO());
```

The output of the above code is

```
DayJS
2022-03-17T15:00:00Z 
Luxon
2022-03-17T16:00:00.000Z
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/luxon-playground-forked-k6rfcl?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that you correctly [configured timezone support in Day.js](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/timezone)? They produce the same results:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.11.0/plugin/utc.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.11.0/plugin/timezone.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.11.0/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="module">

import {DateTime} from 'https://unpkg.com/luxon@2.3.1/src/luxon.js';

const {dayjs} = window;
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_utc);
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_timezone);

const isoString = '2022-03-17T16:00:00Z';

const dj1 = dayjs(isoString);
const djtz1 = dj1.tz('America/Los_Angeles');

const lux1 = DateTime.fromISO(isoString).setZone('America/Los_Angeles');

console.log({dayjs: djtz1.utc().format()});
console.log({luxon: lux1.setZone('utc').toISO()});

</script>
```

Comment: I'm sure. It is a confirmed bug with dayjs. The issue is going from dayjs UTC to a TZ back to UTC while in DST.

Comment: I just ran it and the results were different - dayjs was 1 hour behind, as OP said.